# Docker container backup and restoration with external volumes

Tags: docker

I am in the process of setting up the backup process for my Docker containers, but it seems that it is natively not simple for the containers which are using the external volumes. My container's static as well as dynamic data (the complete data) is in a single Linux folder.

The first option is to just take the backup of complete folder on Linux level and restore it when needed to bring up the container.

The second option is by creating image using Docker commit and take the backup of volumes as usual on Linux level.

Now, I am unable to figure out the pros and cons for both of the options. Is there any third option available which is better than these two options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about data containers? https://hackernoon.com/docker-data-containers-cb250048d162

Comment: Thanks, The article says to use docker export command but as per the export documentation "The docker export command does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an existing directory in the container, docker export will export the contents of the underlying directory, not the contents of the volume."